# Why does a count using React Hooks useState() alternate between two numbers?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

The following is a React Hooks experiment of using `useState()`.  It works fine except when the `+` button was clicked on, then the number can be alternating from `7001` and `7000` and then flashing between some numbers quickly.

Actually, without clicking on the `+`, the number behaved well but up to about 8000 or 9000, then it might start to flash between some numbers. Why is that and how can it be fixed?

**P.S.** initial debugging finding was that: it seems `Counter()` was called multiple times, setting up an Interval Timer every time. So "magically", it seems the `useState()` ran only once -- for some unknown and magical reason -- or maybe it ran more than once but just returned the exact same content each time, for some magical mechanism. The initial value of `0` really was so for the first time. When it was `useState(0)` for future times, the `count` was not `0`... we wouldn't want that, but then it wasn't that functional (as in a math function) either.

```js
function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

    setInterval(() => {
        setCount(count + 1000);
    }, 1000);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}> + </button>                    
            { count }
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}> - </button> 
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```css
button { margin: 0 1em }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Code in functional component gets executed every time when component is re-rendered. So, on each re-render you are starting an infinite timer that adds 1000 to counter each second
2. Each time you change component's state, React re-renders it. Meaning, every execution of `setCount` leads to new re-render and new timer is started
3. Also, `setCount` is asynchronous and if you need to rely on previous state to determine next one, you should call with callback, it like demonstrated in other answer (`setCount(c => c + 1)`)

Something like this is supposed to work:

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';

function Counter() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    //useRef gives us an object to store things between re-renders
    const timer = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
      timer.current = setInterval(() => {
        setCount(count => count + 1000);
      }, 1000);

      //If we return a function, it will be called when component is dismounted
      return () => {
        clearInterval(timer.current);
      }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count => count + 1)}> + </button>                    
            { count }
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count => count - 1)}> - </button> 
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: so how do you fix it

Comment: @nonopolarity see updated answer (might not work properly though, as I didn't test it)

Comment: I thought `useEffect(fn)` is supposed to make that function `fn` run after every render?

Comment: @nonopolarity if 2nd argument provided (an array) React checks if any prop in that array were changed. Empty array makes function run only on first render

Comment: is it true that you can just keep the timerID in a local variable, and let the returned function clear that timerID because that returned function is a closure? So can skip the useRef()

Comment: @nonopolarity Yes, I think it's true. [Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) also has such example. I just used `useRef` without thinking too much

Comment: there is one such case where useRef() is needed... if somehow other function needs to clear it, such as a event handler... then it has no such access to that scope...

Comment: @nonopolarity yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure about the 'why is that' but it's fixed with substituting `setCount(c => c + 1)` in the buttons and `setCount(c => c + 1000)` in the interval.

Putting the 'setInterval' in an effect also makes sure that there is only one interval...

```
  React.useEffect(() => {  
     setInterval(() => {
        setCount(c => c + 1000);
     }, 1000);
  },[])
```

**PS** `Counter()` gets called on every render, I think... while `useState` only gets called once per mounting by design.

Comment: "Counter() gets called on every render, I think... while useState only gets called once per mounting by design." ... so we are in a state of "weird" programming? Some lines in a function is executed every time but some only once?

Comment: I think that is one of the ideas of using hooks in React... some control over what runs how often. The initial value and function of `state` only needs to be defined once, other parts of a component might need to be updated if a specific variable changes, while others need to be updated every time the component re-renders. That might indeed be a bit weird...

Comment: guess what, `useState()` is acutally called multiple time, and how does `count` get a new value to be re-rendered? It is exactly by `[count, setCount] = useState(0)`

Comment: you're absolutely right of course :-) thanks for the hint